# Symfony PHP Event Listener not working

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I have a system where a user can create an order. As soon as the order is created another entity table should be updated with the current user who created the order, the time he created it, and some other information.

Basically a Log.

Here is my Listener class;

```
namespace Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Lib\PurchaseModule;

use Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Entity\Business\PurchaseModule\PmodLog;
use Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Entity\Business\PurchaseModule\PmodOrder;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

/**
 * Class OrderLogger. Purchase Module activity logger.
 */
class OrderLogger
{
    /**
     * Service container
     * @var type 
     */
    private $serviceContainer;

    /**
     * Performs tasks before destruction
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $order = $args->getEntity();

        if ($order instanceof PmodOrder) {
            $logRecord = new PmodLog();

            $user = $this->serviceContainer->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

            $logRecord->setCreatedBy($user);
            $logRecord->setAction('Gemaak');
            $logRecord->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $logRecord->setOrder($order);
            $logRecord->setDepartment($user->getDepartment());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sales order exporter object
     * @param type $serviceContainer
     */
    public function setServiceContainer($serviceContainer)
    {
        $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;
    }
}
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong and that the log table in my database doesn't get updated whatsoever.

Here is my service as well;

```
bss.pmod.logger:
    class: Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Lib\PurchaseModule\OrderLogger
    calls:
    - [ setServiceContainer, [@service_container] ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

I don't get an error, the order is perfectly created but the log database remain empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well don't you need to **persist** and **flush** `$logRecord`? You can get the entity manager from `$args`.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I was aware of that persist and flush and tried `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` but that will only work in controllers, right?

I didn't knew that I can get the entity manager from `$args`.

Comment: See http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.LifecycleEventArgs.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt this to yours. Right after someone creates a `User` entity, a new `UserLog` entity/record gets created by inserting some data from `User` entity as well.

**Controller**

```
public function createAction()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername('username');
    $user->setPassword('password');

    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

**Services.yml**

```
services:
    application_backend.event_listener.user_entity:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\UserEntityListener
        tags:
                - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

**UserEntityListener.php**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\User;
use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\UserLog;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class UserEntityListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $log = new UserLog();
            $log->setUserId($entity->getId());
            $log->setMessage('postPersist at ' . date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));

            $em = $args->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($log);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work from @dlondero's answer, but yours would have done the trick as well. Have my upvote (will show when I get 15 rep).

Comment: I think you shouldn't flush things inside an event listener. Right now, u're flushing twice, first in the listener, bound to postPersist, then in the controller (but this one is flushing nothing). I would remove the flush() (but keep the persist) in the listener, and let the controller handle the flush().